# I noticed I'm overcharged for my internet in Australia. Where to complain?

Tags: internet, australia, commerce

I have subscribed to an internet service in Australia and they overcharged me.

They are not following laws.
I have found a few resources to prove they are in wrong.

https://www.business.gov.au/products-and-services/fair-trading/displaying-prices

https://www.accc.gov.au/business/pricing-surcharging/displaying-prices

I contacted them, and they offered me a refund for my payment.
But I want more, I want them to give me the promised price and I want them to stop the misleading advertising.

Can you please give practical advice? When I know their action was illegal:

What can I do?
Where should I complain?

Answer (score 4):

> I want them to give me the promised price ...

You can’t make them do this. A business that has posted an incorrect price is **not** obliged to sell for that price.

See https://law.stackexchange.com/a/4466/344

> ... and I want them to stop the Misleading advertising

You can’t stop them yourself but you can report them to the relevant authorities. These are the ones you linked to: NSW Fair Trading for state law breach and the ACCC for Commonwealth breaches. Misleading pricing is a breach of both state and Federal law.

> Can you please give a practical advice?

No. If you want legal advice, hire a lawyer.

> What can I do? Where should I complain?

See above.